# How to return list of files in directory using GraphQL query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, express-graphql

I need a list of files in folder, returned with GraphQL query. Can someone explain, how to configure the type and resolver the list? I have some configuration with fs() method, but it doesn't return the list of files. There's a code of schema and resolvers below. To shorten the code, I removed some resolvers that are not related to files.
Will be very grateful for any help!

schema.js

```
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

module.exports = buildSchema(`
type Hero {
  _id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String
  date: String!
}
type File {
  path: String
}
input HeroInput {
  title: String!
  description: String!
  date: String!
}
input HeroUpdate {
  _id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String
  date: String!
} 
input HeroRemove {
  _id: ID! 
} 
type RootQuery {
  heroes: [Hero!]!
  findHero(id: ID!): Hero
  files: File
}
type RootMutation {
  createHero(heroInput: HeroInput): Hero
  deleteHero(heroRemove: HeroRemove): Hero
  updateHero(heroUpdate: HeroUpdate): Hero
}
schema {
  query: RootQuery
  mutation: RootMutation
}
`);
```

resolvers.js

```
const Hero = require('./models/hero');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  files: () => {
    const filesPath = path.join(__dirname, './files');
    return fs.readdir(filesPath, function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
      }  
      console.log(files);    
      return files.map(file => {
        return {
          path: file
        };
      });
    });
  },
  heroes: () => {
    return Hero.find()
      .then(heroes => {
        return heroes.map(hero => {
          return { 
            ...hero._doc, 
            _id: hero.id,
            date: new Date(hero.date).toISOString()
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: You'll want to return a promise in your resolver.  Use `fs.promises.readdir` instead.

Comment: Fs returns the list of files, but the query doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to configure the File type and query in schema.js

```
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

module.exports = buildSchema(`
type Hero {
  _id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String
  date: String!
}
type File {
  path: String
}
input HeroInput {
  title: String!
  description: String!
  date: String!
}
input HeroUpdate {
  _id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String
  date: String!
} 
input HeroRemove {
  _id: ID! 
} 
type RootQuery {
  heroes: [Hero!]!
  findHero(id: ID!): Hero
  files: [File]
}
type RootMutation {
  createHero(heroInput: HeroInput): Hero
  deleteHero(heroRemove: HeroRemove): Hero
  updateHero(heroUpdate: HeroUpdate): Hero
}
schema {
  query: RootQuery
  mutation: RootMutation
}
`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `files` resolver does not work as expected because you are returning `fs.readdir`. However, the function is asynchronous and therefore immediately returns `undefined` instead of the result of your callback function.

To avoid this problem you could use `fs.readdirSync` instead of `fs.readdir`:

```
files: () => {
  const filesPath = path.join(__dirname, './files');
  const files = fs.readdirSync(filesPath);  
  return files.map(file => ({path: file}));
}
```

*Note: I used a shorthand notation for the `map` function in order to immediately return the object!*

Documentation of `fs.readdirSync`: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options

Hope this solved your problem :)

Cheers,
derbenoo

Comment: anyway, it returns a null result:
{
  "data": {
    "files": {
      "path": null
    }
  }
}
Could the problem be related to the schema and the File type?

Comment: Files contains array:
[ '11265-background-ne.jpg',
  'C_2_fotogallery_3083525_1_image.jpg',
  'drakensberg-river-207835.jpg',
  'South Africa Header Image.jpg',
  'Sunset-at-Alpe-di-Siusi.jpg' ]